# how to check "$" using pregmatch

Tags: php, regex

I have the below code.

```
            $require = for;
            $f = "/$".$require."/";
            if (preg_match($f, $code, $match)) :
             print "Match found!";
            endif;
```

I want to display match found if `$for` was found in the string. My idea above is just to integrate `$` and `for` to make it `$for`.

I'm new in using regex :)

I don't know if I'm doing the correct way.

Need help thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape dollar signs in regular expressions -- unescaped they are a lookaround token for the end of the string.

```
$f = "/\\$" . $require . "/";
```